# How can we find availability of a Calendar using Zapier Natural Language Actions

Tags: zapier, langchain, py-langchain

Recently, I discovered the Zapier Langchain tool and decided to give it a try. The setup process was straightforward, and everything worked seamlessly. While using the "Google Calendar: Find event" function, I realized that it only works with the [search_term] parameter, and there doesn't seem to be an option to check for slot availability, as also mentioned in this [link](https://community.zapier.com/how-do-i-3/checking-availability-741).

I'm curious if there's a workaround for this limitation. Is there a way to determine if a time slot is open for scheduling, while using the Zapier toolkit?

I'm quite new to Zapier and simply followed the step-by-step instructions provided [here](https://nla.zapier.com/start/) and [here](https://blog.langchain.dev/langchain-zapier-nla/) for setup and usage. You can view my workflow in action below
[image]